# Why $ax + by + c = 0$ if $y = ax + c$?

Tags: calculus

Apologies for a potentially stupid question, but I am wondering why the [two standard formats of expressing the linear equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) lead to a different solution?

$ax + by + c = 0$

$by = -ax -c$

$y = -ax - c$, if slope of y = 1

And the common format of writing the equation

$y = ax + c$, where a is the slope of x and c the y-intercept

Obviously, b has to be -1 in the first equation, but do we not just write $y = -ax -c$?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You say the two formats lead to different solutions. What solutions are you talking about?

Comment: @5xum assuming b=1

Comment: a and c simply represent numbers, positive, negative or 0. Then -a and -c simply represent numbers too. When you compute their values you will get unique vulues and a unique line.

Comment: In order to make sure it is clear... you have many different equally valid ways of expressing a linear equation.  You could do it as $\color{blue}{A}x+\color{blue}{B}y+\color{blue}{C}=0$ or you could do it as $y=\color{red}{a}x+\color{red}{c}$, or you could do it as $\color{green}{c}=\dfrac{x-\color{green}{x_0}}{y-\color{green}{y_0}}$ or a number of other ways.  It sounds as though you are thinking that $\color{red}{a}$ and $\color{blue}{A}$ need to be the same number.  They don't.

Comment: @Paul, right. I guess what I am wondering here is that if I solved the second equation, I would get a different answer compared to the first one unless I knew that b = -1 in the first equation.

Comment: Moderators, if you think that this question is not helpful for others, please delete it.

Comment: @JMoravitz, right. That's what I was thinking. I found it confusing that people use the same symbols for different things (thanks to you and user289143, I understand now that those symbols do not mean the same thing). Regarding the downvotes, please let me delete this question for f*cks shake. If it is too basic here, fine, now I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a line with the standard form $ax+by+c=0$, or in the case $b \neq 0$ you can pass in the gradient form: $y=mx+q$ where $m=-\frac{a}{b}$ and $q=-\frac{c}{b}$. So you can use the gradient form for all lines except the lines parallel to the $y$-axis, where $b=0$ and then $ax+by+c=0$ leads to $x=-\frac{c}{a}$.